# is_mobile as shortcode

Tags: shortcode, conditional-tags

I installed the Plugin "mobble" which provides some more conditional tags. As I want to hide some content for mobile devices I tried to build a shortcode [is_mobile]. But I tried many different ways with `return  do_shortcode($content);` and `return  $content;`or `return apply_filters('the_content', $content);`but it's simply not doing what I want.. ;(

```
add_shortcode( 'is_mobile', 'is_mobile_shortcode' );

function is_mobile_shortcode( $atts, $content = null) {
     if ( !is_mobile( ) );
        return $content;
    return '';
}
```

I would be very happy about some help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra ";" after `if ( !is_mobile( ) );` Your code should look like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'is_mobile', 'is_mobile_shortcode' );

function is_mobile_shortcode( $atts, $content = null) {
     if ( !is_mobile( ) )
        return $content;
    return '';
}
```

And you'll use it in this way (just for to be sure you're using it right:

```
[is_mobile]My Caption[/is_mobidle]
```